# how to write a function that recursively sum the digits

Tags: python

I need a function that takes variables and then computes these variables (example for x and y x**y) and recursively finds the sum of points there is two left.
But,
The function needs to print all the calculation.
For an example
Function is going to print this,5**3
Sorry for my bad english and good luck with the question.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you have tried and where you are stuck. Pseudocode or a basic description of your approach would be fine if you don't have actual code yet.

Comment: If you want to create a new question you should not reuse this one.

Comment: If you have your answer, mark it as the correct one. If you want to ask a new question [create a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

Not very beautiful, but does the job

```
def f(x, y):
    tmp =  x**y
    sum = 0
    while tmp >= 1:
        sum = sum + tmp % 10
        tmp = (tmp // 10)
    return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do it for you.
Not the most pretty code either:

```
def func(x,y):
    
    res1 = str(x**y)
    to_print = "{0}^{1} = {2}".format(x,y,res1)
    
    while len(res1) > 1:
        to_print += " = " + res1[0]
        res2 = int(res1[0])
        for n in res1[1:]:
            to_print += " + " + n
            res2 += int(n)

        to_print += " = " + str(res2)
        res1 = str(res2)
        
    print(to_print)
```

Basically I created a string from the value of `x**y` so it would be easy to iterate(`res1 = str(x**y)`).

---

`to_print` saves the final output and is used to concatenate all the values.

```
to_print = "{0}^{1} = {2} = {3}".format(x,y,res1, res1[0])
```

I used a format string, if you are unfamiliar with this [check this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp).

---

`res2` saves the sum of the digits:

```
res2 = int(res1[0])
for n in res1[1:]:
        res2 += int(n)
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark next to it! Thx